# Threads in Java max amount?

Tags: java, multithreading, networking

So I'm making a Java Server for a game I'm making and I was wondering if creating a thread for each player is an overkill, having in mind the server might take a high number of people online at the same time.

How many threads is to many?, Should I make 1 Thread per game (Its the lobby type game, where you select a match and enter) or is 1 Thread per player good?

Comment: It depends.  What are these threads doing?

Comment: Basically the threads are checking and processing the messages from that player, checking its movement and shooting.

Comment: You could do this as one thread per engine or one per player or a few threads for the engine and two thread per connection.  This is no fixed answer on how you should do this.  Note:  more threads are not always better and you often find your application is slower with large numbers of threads.  How big is large varies.  2 GB of memory is not very much these days you can bug 32 GB for a reasonable price. Whether you need it or not I cannot say.

Comment: Define 'high number'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This soley depends on your application architecture. There are couple of thing that we need to know before going to conclusion.

1. if you create infinite nof the threads of each request then you application will suffer from resource over utilization and you may get outofmemory errors or CPU over utilization
2. if you create very less no of threads then your application will suffer from liveliness
3. that to if we create a thread on the fly it needs considerable amount of resource also

So its better to have ThreadPool and the thread pool should have fixed nof of threads in it. like  `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(NO_OF_THREADS);`

At the same time we should have a rejection policy in our arsenal, and some of them are e.g. `Silent discard, discard with an exception, caller runner (back push so that it will slowdown request inflow the way normal networks work) and discard old (depends on your priority set)`.

Both the above things will give you a robust system. sorry if you feel i could not answer your question properly.

Edit: I am answering as per the below query.

1. You can test your application by jmeter and see how your application perform. You can also do some **distributed load testing** with JMeter by combing some workstations also. It will give you the real picture and whats the thread you should have to serve a typical workload.
2. sometimes formulas like `no of threads = 2 * no_of_cores * no_of_disks * percentage CPU utilization you need  * (1 + (W/ C))`

***(W/C) is the fraction stating Wait time to Compute time.***

Comment: Ok, but I have a question with the following specs linux VPS 8 cores, 2 GB of ram (I can order more ram if needed), how many threads could I run?
I will look into FixedThreadPool, from what I read on java docs it seems what I need.

Comment: I see, JMeter looks very promising.
Thansk

Answer (score 0):

I made threads in my game for each player and there was 20-30 threads in the same time and there was no lagg. So for each player I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking how many threads you can create before bringing you system down,
it will probably be a few thousands threads, it depends on your operating system and on how much memory each thread needs.

We can't make this design choice for you since we don't know what each thread does, but if using a thread for each game counts, and if optimization counts for your purpose (desired scalability of the system? commercial or homework?), I would go for as less threads as possible.

Comment: I will host the server in a linux VPS 8 cores, 2 GB of ram (if needed I can expand it)